# CSS @media not (min-width) not working

Tags: css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WfgvT/)

When resize the result below 400px, the `@media not (min-width: 400px)` not working, I know I could use `@media (max-width: 399px)`, but I want to know why not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
@media not screen and (min-width: 400px)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QYrM3/)

Comment: Thanks, it work =), and I found a [reference](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Comment: It would be great to know why this has been down voted ? I know I don't answer the "Why" but at least this is a workaround...

Comment: MDN says `@media` syntax is `media_query: [[only | not]? <media_type> [ and <expression> ]*] | <expression> [ and <expression> ]*`, so if we use `only` or `not` we must has `media_type`, [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

min-width 400px means the device should atleast have a width of 400px.
The rules you have written for min-width: 400px won't work when you resize your window below 400px.

max-width: 399px means the maximum width is 399px. rules written for max-width 399px will work when you have resized the window below 399px.